# Sending an authorization token from parent window to iframe origin so that iframe origin could make the call

Tags: javascript, iframe, authorization, bearer-token

I am developing a SDK that enables to accept online card payments for e-commerce companies (merchants) who do not have the right to possess credit card data (cc_data). Currently I am struggling to come up with a proper solution for securing the API.

****The currents solution** uses stateless sessions (that will not be changed) and is following:**

Payment form initialization

- Merchant makes an API call to initiate a payment using http basic authentication;
- As a response, merchant is given payment links and a token;
- Merchant uses payment links to call iframes: there is an iframe for each input (name, cc_number etc), including submit as a iframe as well. This shall offer as little pre-design as possible so that merchant could design its own payment form;

Iframes, collecting cc_data and submitting

- For every iframe there is a corresponding html with javascript. E.g. name.html with name.js, submit.html with submit.js. The data from inputs gets stored into sessionstorage;
- Once the submit is pushed, submit.js will make AJAX call to payment API endpoint (our own server, so for internal security CSRF token is used) to post the cc_date.

**Issue**

The existing payment API endpoints requires a token that was given to merchant as well, but I have not found a reasonable solution to get it from the merchant, because the system is stateless. In a way, my solution is not following the standard token authorization, where the token is given for the user to authorize its actions, because the user (in my case merchant) is not calling the action. I am calling it using only a CSRF token given by my own server.

**Possible solutions**

In a way it seemed to me that perhaps I should drop the idea of an token authorization at all, because this is not a case for it - merchant is not making the call, thus no need to authorize (and during payment initiation it authenticated itself already). But some developers did point out that CSRF token might not be secure enough in my situation, because they have a possibility to access it (e.g. imitating web browser, where the token is saved) and then they are able to abuse the payment API endpoint during the time that the token is valid.

Taking into account the beforementioned, I am still trying to find a solution to communicate authorization token in a way that would enable API security. The obvious possible solution is to use postMessage() for sending the token from merchant (parent window) to submit.js (iframe origin). But I did not fancy this idea very much, because there are many possible origins, where the token could come from and thus I cannot make a reasonable filter, where I am excepting the message from. Posting the token to server is not an option, because it is stateless... and calling iframes to not offer the possibility to include headers.

**Suggesting ideas**

So currently I am looking for solutions and thought that the Stackoverflow might be the best place to ask advise. Perhaps I should change my current proof of concept totally (meaning that there is no good solution to my issue), so advise on that level is welcome as well. Of course, then it is important to take into account that the server is stateless, cc_data must not reach the merchant and the overall payment form's design should be under merchant's control as much as possible.

Thank you for your advice in advance.

This is my first time posting in Stackoverflow (I started as a junior developer only few weeks ago) and a new and interesting experience.

EDIT:
**Business need**

- Payments without redirection, the payment form is displayed on merchant's site;
- Merchant should have as much control as possible over the payment form design (when initializing payment, merchant can choose styles for iframe origins as well);
- The merchant shall have no access to the cc_data (or possess it in a form that is understandable to the merchant)

Comment: Why can the merchant not provide the token on the request?  Either as a `?token=` query string (not recommented), or as a custom header on an ajax request, such as `X-Custom-Token` or something (recommended as it is not exposed on the url).  Or if it is a post request, it could be a query string, since it would be in the post body and not exposed on the url.

Comment: I guess it would help you (and maybe us trying to understand what you're looking for) to clearly state which party (the user, the merchant) is allowed to take which action. Also I would consider wether you really need an iframe, cause iframes allow a lot of communication between the parent and the iframe, which opens a lot of possible ways to circumvent security. All payment providers I used redirected to theeir site at some point, then redirected back to the origin once the payment was authorized.

Comment: @Taplar The merchant gets the token only after payment initialization. If the merchant would post the token to server after that, there would not be a way to communicate it to the browser, where the submit.js is situated, because the server itself is stateless (meaning that the server has no memory of an submit.js that was called few seconds earlier).

I actually though that some kind of state-machine (where I would save states and access them with submit.js)  would be a good idea, but I have not found a secure solution yet.

Comment: This process cannot be entirely stateless.  Because, as far am I am understanding the question, you have a series of steps involving iframes that have to happen before they can submit.  The data collected from those steps has to be stored *somewhere*.  I see in the question that you say the value are stored in `sessionStorage`.  So that is storage of state on the client, within the iframes.  The issue with that is `sessionStorage` is not shared between windows, which includes iframes.  So while the data is associated with the site in the iframe, which presumably means all the iframs are, ...

Comment: ..., then you could potentially grab all that information on the submit and pass it again, but you cannot since it is in `sessionStorage`.  One option would be to change it from `sessionStorage` to `localStorage`, which **is** shared on the browser for all associated same domain pages.  So theoretically you could store each piece in localStorage when they enter it, and then when you submit the final part, it could grab all of that out of localStorage and send it all at once.

Comment: Granted, if any site runs into users who have localStorage/sessionStorage disabled, this whole process would fail.

Comment: @JonasWilms, Thank you for your suggestions, I added a new section to my question specifying the business need behind my solution.

@Taplar, getting the data from `localstorage` is not actually an issue for me now, because currently I successfully collect cc_data. The issue is getting the token from merchant and for that I cannot use `sessionstorage` nor `localstorage`, because origins are different (merchant does not have access to my `localstorage` and vica-versa).

Comment: "Payments without redirection, the payment form is displayed on merchant's site" is that really a business need? If so, why? Giving merchants control over how a payment form looks like that directly authorizes a payment sounds like a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually solved this myself the very next day, but I wanted to check my solution in practice first. The answer is actually quite simple: **double submit cookies**.

So basically, whenever submit.html is called with submit.js (iframe button responsible for sending the payment data to API endpoint), it will get a CRSF token from the back-end server. The server will attach an encrypted cookie to submit.html as well, using https secure cookies.

Now, whenever the submit.js makes a call to the API endpoint, the CSRF token will be sent back with header. Back-end server takes encrypted cookie that it attached to submit.html, decrypts and compares it to the CRSF token in the header. If there is a match, the request is valid.

More info could be found here: [OWASP cheat cheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#double-submit-cookie).